# Can we do SEM incase we dont have any data for dependent variable?

Tags: regression, correlation, dataset, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I need to study the impact of various factors on gender sensitisation. The research instrument was created and factor analysis was done using EFA. Now further structural equation modelling has to be performed on AMOS to analyse the affect of the factors on gender sensitization. but i don't have any questionnaire set pertaining to gender sensitization for running SEM. only one questionnaire was framed on gender sensitization through which i have extracted the factors. Kindly assist me that how should I go ahead and perform SEM analysis.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Can you clarify? If you don't have a variable, what are you going to do?

Comment: Thanks for the response.Basically I created a questionnaire for gender sensitization as a whole and then computed some factors for the same using efa in spss and confirmed the same using cfa in amos.I wanted to know based on only this dataset can we run sem to study the impact of each factor on gender sensitization?I read that we can impute the data for the factors based on the associated independent variables for each factor.Can we similary impute the data for gender sensitization based on the entire question set of gender sensitisation and then do a sem based on these data points?